# sms access project

Tags: iphone

i was searching on the net for a method which can inform an incoming message on receivers phone.
 but everyone said it is not possible

but there is an app. which is approved from apple
here is the url

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tigertext/id355832697?mt=8

if i am not wrong this is doing similar kind of work...(i.e. accessing incoming sms)

please reply i am waiting...

and sorry if i  am wrong about the working of that app...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not sms, but an alternative chat protocol, most probably using the push notification service.

Comment: thank you very much
i want to make app. and want to use Private APIs but dont know how to use and where to get....
please help

Comment: i have an jailbreaked iphone and need to make this app for college purpose only....